# Pandas: conditional rolling count by group, counting the number of times current observation appeared in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do a rolling count of the observations appearing in one column given a fixed window length by group specified in another column. This is better explained with an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': ['X', 'X' , 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'X', 'Y'],
                   'group': ["IT", "IT", "IT", "MV", "MV", "MV", "IT", "MV", "MV", "IT", "IT", "MV"]})
```

I would like to groupby 'group' and do a rolling count of the 'X's and 'Y's in column B with window length = 3. If 'X' is the current row, then we want to count the number of times 'X' appeared in the previous 3 observations within group 'group', not including the count of the current row (so shift back by period=1). For this example, I also need min_periods=1.

The output should look like

```
     B group  count
0    X    IT    0
1    X    IT    1
2    Y    IT    0
3    X    MV    0
4    Y    MV    0
5    Y    MV    1
6    X    IT    2
7    X    MV    1
8    Y    MV    2
9    Y    IT    1
10   X    IT    1
11   Y    MV    2
```

I've tried the following code but it is not quite correct. This counts by 'group' and 'B'. The count should rather be by 'group' and observations in 'B' should be counted over the last 3 periods within 'group'.

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(['group', 'B']).transform(lambda x: x.rolling(3, min_periods=1).count().shift(fill_value=0))
```

Comment: Can you explain how you arrived at 1 and 2 for row index 10 and 11?

Comment: looking at row 10 for example. Using your formulation, this counts the number of times 'X' and 'IT' occurred together over the last 3 times they occurred together. Instead, I want the number of times 'X' and 'IT' occurred together over the last 3 times 'IT' occurred on its own... If you look at the previous 'IT's, it occurred twice with 'Y' and 1 with 'X', hence the value 1.

Comment: Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution below but I am looking for a better one as column 'B' could potentially have many different observations making it quite slow.

```
for i in df['B'].unique():
    df.loc[df['B']==i, 'count'] = df.where(df['B'].eq(i)).groupby(df['group'])['B'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(3, min_periods=1).count().shift(fill_value=0))
df

    B group count
0   X   IT  0.0
1   X   IT  1.0
2   Y   IT  0.0
3   X   MV  0.0
4   Y   MV  0.0
5   Y   MV  1.0
6   X   IT  2.0
7   X   MV  1.0
8   Y   MV  2.0
9   Y   IT  1.0
10  X   IT  1.0
11  Y   MV  2.0
```